# make contents inline

Tags: css, drupal

I have a content type which has an image and a body and I want them to be inlined . the class of all nodes in HTML file is ".content" and I wrote my css like this:

```
.content{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

but it doesn't work . anyone has any experience with this?
thanks

Comment: Could you post the markup your using?

Comment: Some browsers, particularly IE <=7 , don't support inline-block at all or only partly.

Comment: IE is finicky about which elements it renders as expected using :inline-block. IE6/7 require those elements to be native inline elements (p, a, span). Older FF versions were unreliable as well.

Answer (score 1):

display:inline-block doesn't work in all browsers.  If you want actual inline-block behavior, see here (it's complicated):

http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

If you actually want your .content to go inline, then use display:inline instead of display:inline-block.

Comment: thanks , I did a css selecting and it worked fine  . inside the .content was .field-item which was selected for every node . and I add img tag to specify my image . like this ".field-item img{float:right; clear:right; }" and it worked the way I wanted .  thanks

Answer (score 0):

For IE7 you need to use:

```
.content{
    display: inline-block;
    *zoom:1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

This will display inline-block for every browser, except for old versions of IE.  IE had a css property(which you could not set through css) called 'hasLayout'.  Haslayout is essentialy block (you can style it with widths etc.), but you have to trigger it through 'zoom:1;'.

The asterisks (*) are for IE only styles.